# Load an iFrame to Drupal with JavaScript

Tags: theming, javascript, google-analytics

Because of Google Analytics I would need to use JavaScipt to load iFrame to my Drupal template. I use this only just on one custom content type template.

Can I put the JavaScript straight to the template?

At the moment the JavaScript in my node template is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var iframe = document.getElementById('myIFrame');
iframe.src = pageTracker._getLinkerUrl('http://mydomain.com/iframepage/');

</script>

<iframe id="myIFrame" height="500px" width="350"></iframe>
```

But it doesn't load anything to the iFrame. I followed this http://code.google.com/intl/fi/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSite.html#trackingIFrames

Any idea where the problem is?

EDIT: noticed that I get error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: pageTracker is not defined"

Comment: If you think you do everything correct, check "[X-Frame-Options][1]" of your URL.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options/10174077

Comment: Can I somehow find out that if its that?

Comment: open your site with Google Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Your code is missing some important stuff. The original code from the Google page you linked yourself:

```
_gaq.push(function() {
  var pageTracker = _gat._getTrackerByName();
  var iframe = document.getElementById('myIFrame');
  iframe.src = pageTracker._getLinkerUrl('http://www.my-example-iframecontent.com/');
});
```

So you would end up with something like the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">_gaq.push(function () {
  document.getElementById('myIFrame').src = _gat._getTrackerByName()._getLinkerUrl('http://www.my-example-iframecontent.com/');
});</script>
<iframe id="myIFrame" height="500px" width="350"></iframe>
```